# Distributing load in electrical panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel, electrical-distribution

I am in the process of rewiring my house. The house was built in 1950 and even though the service panel was upgraded in the early 70's to a Square D 200 amp service, the system is ungrounded and will not handle today's electrical load requirements. So I am replacing all of the wire, switches, receptacles and placing the wire in non-metallic conduits.

My question is what is the best practice for separating the different loads into various circuits. I am putting the microwave on a dedicated circuit, but how should I separate the rest of the loads in the house. There are no other high power loads in the house.

Comment: Check your local inspection rules. Most will at least require that the work be left visible until a pro has reviewed it. In some areas there is a specific course required, plus I spection parteay thry the project and at the end -- this is actually a good thing since the course teaches you everything from max.number of connections in a given size box to whether wires must be run on the surface of joists of can be drilled thru -- and how to drill without weakening the joist, and whether/how many multiple wires can pass thru the approved hole... Do it right the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what code requires, there are various things that you might choose to do, depending on your mindset, that are not code required (nor do they conflict with code.) For instance, I prefer to keep all lighting circuits completely separate from any outlet circuits, having basically never had  light fixtures blow a fuse/trip a breaker, but having stumbled though the dark to the fusebox (yes, literally, fuses) too many times once upon a house when outlet overloads took out combined circuits (I think there were a total of 6.)

i.e. you have chosen to give the microwave its own outlet. I prefer that the refrigerator also not share (I don't recall if code does that), code requires two separate 20A countertop outlet circuits, and I'd also put a separate light circuit in the kitchen (that might share with other rooms' lights, depending on load.)

Likewise code has some specific language and requirements for bathrooms, primarily hair-dryer-driven.

Remember that code specifies the minimum you must do; it does not limit what you do beyond that, so long as what you do meets it.

Comment: Just for your own future reference; NEC 2014 210.52(B)(1) covers the small appliances and includes the 'refrigeration equipment', but Exception #2 allows the 'refrigeration equipment' to be on it's own dedicated circuit if desired (which is typical).

Comment: Digression re hair drier: Most recent hotel room built a small vanity with tip-ip mirror  into one of the top desk drawers, and stored (and plugged in) the hair drier there. After all, there's no good reason you have to use it in the bathroom if a mirror is available elsewhere. Elegant way to completely dodge that whole set of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in an area that follows the National Electrical Code (most of The United States), it provides a list of all the required circuits.  That should provide you with a good starting point.

Unfortunately, the section that covers this is quite long, so I'm not going to quote the entire text here. It's quite a bit of information to cover, so even summarizing all the codes involved would be too much for a short answer format.

Before embarking on such a large project, I'd suggest you take some time to learn as much as you can. Rewiring an entire house is a huge project, and one that should not be tackled by a novice. Get a copy of the version of the National Electrical Code that's adopted in your area. Read it, study it, understand it. Then you *might* be ready to begin.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have a fair amount of school in electronics and experience working on shipboard electrical systems. I have also installed many individual home electrical circuits but I have not taken on rewiring an entire house. And you are correct, this is a major project but I do want to do it correctly. I was forced to begin the project already because we lost power in several parts of the house so I have not been able to proceed as I would have liked in a systematic fashion. So any more suggestions are truly welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you've got the NEC to abide by, but remember that it's only there to create the minimum requirements. You can get a copy of it, but there is also free viewing online of any version.

> Click "Free access to the 2014 edition of NFPA 70" (The NEC - you'll have to sign up, it's free)
>
> http://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/document-information-pages?mode=code&code=70
>
> On the same page you can find a link to the map of the US showing which states have adopted which code. Also by clicking "Current & Prior Editions", you can find a drop down on that page to access the older copies. All the way back to the 1993 version will have a free PDF to view.

In your case, you will want to mainly focus on sections 210 and 220. These will give you the majority of the requirements. Like I said at first though, honestly if you just draw up a quick sketch of your house and mark where all you want power at, it'll check most of the boxes. Follow the requirements, but the biggest issue (as is your problem now) is to just don't bog down the circuits. A 200A service should very well cover you, especially if the microwave is one of the biggest loads you've got.

Like the answer from Ecnerwal said, separate the lighting from your receptacles. Then know that basically receptacles are counted as 180W each in calculation. If you're going with 20A devices and breakers (#12 wire), then that gives you basically 2400W (13 outlets) until the breaker would trip; 15A devices (#14 wire) would allow 1800W (10 outlets). Although it very well depends on what the intended use of the receptacles are for, you'll be fine with say 5-7 receptacles per circuit. Especially since you probably won't have them all pumping power at once and hopefully don't plan to feed a room full of space heaters.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the NEC book, that helps a lot. I am using 14 Ga to the majority of the receptacles with the 15 amp breaker you suggest. I am planning on running 1 dedicated 20 am breaker with 12 Ga wire to each room to allow for a heavy load in each room if needed, I.E. space heater. I was considering building a distribution board in the attic above the load center. Then using junction boxes bring the power up to the board and distribute it to the different points of the house. Would this serve a useful purpose or is it overkill. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a good plan on the receptacles. - Load center = main panel, distribution board = subpanel. The only point of running a sub is for when it's a great distance apart to save on wiring. Like my main is in the basement and feeds it and the first floor, but then I've got a sub on the second floor feeding it. You'd want to have a reason to run one and it actually save money. Also it'd need to be easily accessible for if a breaker trips.